# read the txt file and sort it

Tags: c#, sorting

like the title the txt file like this

the grades is 0~100

sample:

name,grades

name,grades

name,grades

and i have to sort it with grades

is the way to solve it is to split them into array then do the sorting?

i have load the file into the string like this

```
char[] spli = { ' ', ',', '\t' };
        string line;
        string[] sline;

        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(textBox1.Text,Encoding.Default);
        line = file.ReadToEnd();
        sline = line.Split(spli);
        foreach (string item in sline)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(item);

        }
```

plz

Comment: Is that one grade, or multiple grades after the name on the line of the file? If multiple grades, you want to sort it according to diameter, or what?

Comment: You could create a simple object which holds the data elements on each "line" of the text file.  As you read the text file, build a list of those objects.  Then just use the LINQ `.OrderBy()` on that list to sort by the field you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read data from text file and parsing it, always do validation. You never know about the data in file. See my code.

```
class MyListUser
    {
        public string Name;
        public int  Grades;
    }

private List<MyListUser> ReadUserFile()
        {
            List<MyListUser> lstUser;
            string[] sMyData = File.ReadAllLines("Myfile.txt");
            if (sMyData != null)
            {
                MyListUser oTmp;
                string[] sTmp;
                lstUser = new List<MyListUser>();
                for (int i = 0; i < sMyData.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    sTmp = Regex.Split(sMyData[i], ",");
                    //need some validation
                    if (sTmp != null && sTmp.GetLength(0) > 1)
                    {
                        oTmp = new MyListUser();
                        oTmp.Name = sTmp[0];
                        int.TryParse(sTmp[1], out oTmp.Grades );
                        lstUser.Add(oTmp);
                    }
                }
                return lstUser.OrderBy(o => o.Grades).ToList();
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: how to output though the TEXTBOX
thanks for ur code its very helpful

Comment: What do you want to put in textbox? I mean which format?

Comment: like the sample the grades and names

Comment: use the "foeach" loop for List<MyListUser> results and set the textbox value.

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that `grades` in your text file is just a one string representation of one number. You can use LINQ to sort it - first split every line at `,`, then parse the string representation of a number and `OrderBy` it:

```
 var sorted = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text)
                  .OrderBy(line => Int32.Parse(line.Split(',')[1]))
                  .ToList();
```

If the `grades` are a `double`:

```
var sorted = File.ReadLines(textBox1.Text)
                 .OrderBy(line => Double.Parse(line.Split(',')[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                 .ToList();
```